# Centering an image on an HTML5 video background with CSS3

Tags: html, css

first time here so go easy!

I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS in general and I'm trying to create a sort of landing page for a web app project I'm working on.

The idea is to have HTML5 video playing full screen in the background (achieved), with an image in the center of the page to allow users to proceed.

Centering the image is where I'm failing. I can get the image central on the horizontal axis, but not the vertical axis and have been trying all day.

Any ideas how to centralise the image like this http://aberrocreative.com/ or this http://www.ridebarstow.com/ ??

Video:

```
    <video id="video_background" loop autoplay  preload="auto" poster="/images/department.jpg">
    <source src="videos/department1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="videos/department1.ogv" type="video/ogv"/>
    <source src="videos/department1.webm" type="video/webm"/>
    <p>Sorry! It seems your browser doesn't support HTML5 video :( </p>
</video>

#video_background
{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
z-index: -1000;
```

Image:

```
<div id="welcome_image">
    <img src="images/welcome.png" alt="Electronics at York"/>
</div>

#welcome_image {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: box;

-webkit-box-orient: inline-axis;
-moz-box-orient: inline-axis;
box-orient: inline-axis;

-webkit-box-align: end;
-moz-box-align: end;
box-align: end;

-webkit-box-pack: center;
-moz-box-pack: center;
box-pack: center;
z-index: 100;}
```

That image styling is just the latest method I've tried. I'm getting pretty lost!

Yikes, sorry for the code spam and length too!

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

If the parent has *display:flex;* the child will center both horizontally and vertically using *margin:auto;*. To be clear, the child centers within the parent, not the screen, therefore using this particular method the parent is required to fill the screen if that is how you want the child to be centered. There are more ways to center an element, but this is what I've used most recently.

```
#background{
  display:flex;
  position:fixed;
  width:100vw;
  left:0px;
  height:100vh;
  top:0px;
}

#center{
  margin:auto;
}

<div id='background'>
  <div id='center'>Here we go.</div>
</div>
```